# Como faço uma lista aninhada via json com o laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

Estou tentando fazer uma lista aninhada via json, com o laravel, exemplo, a tabela empresas, tem diversos produtos cada empresa, eu quero quando eu clicar em determinada empresa, aparecer os produtos cadastrados apenas naquela empresa que eu cliquei, mas nao estou conseguindo, alguem tem uma ideia?

Minha model:

```
  <?php

     namespace App;

                use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

                class TransferenciaArquivo extends Model
                {
                  protected $table='TransferenciaArquivos';

                  protected $fillable=[
                    'Empresa_id',
                    'Usuario_id',
                    'Assunto',
                    'Email',
                    'Produto_id',
                    'Arquivo',
                    'Comentario',
                    'StatusTransferenciaArquivos_id',
                  ];

                  public function statusTransferenciaArquivos(){
                    return $this->hasOne('App\StatusTransferenciaArquivos','id','StatusTransferenciaArquivos_id');
                  }
                  public function empresasTransferenciaArquivos(){
                    return $this->hasOne('App\Empresa','id','Empresa_id');
                  }
                  public function usuariosTransferenciaArquivos(){
                    return $this->hasMany('App\UsuariosTreinamentos','id','Usuario_id');
                  }
                  public function produtoTransferenciaArquivos(){
                    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto','id','Produto_id');
                  }
                }
```

Estava retornando o produtos assim:

```
                <?php
                $callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ?  $_GET['callback'] : false;
                $conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Mini221190","datamace");

                if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
                  $catID = $_GET['id'];
                } else {
                  $catID = 1;
                }

                $selecao  = "SELECT p.id, p.Nome FROM Produtos p inner join empresas_produtos pe on p.id = pe.Produto_id WHERE Empresa_id = {$catID}";
                $produtos = mysqli_query($conecta,$selecao);

                $retorno = array();
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($produtos)) {
                  $retorno[] = $linha;
                }

                echo json_encode($retorno);

                // fechar conecta
                mysqli_close($conecta);
                ?>
```

e as empresas assim:

```
                <?php
                $callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ?  $_GET['callback'] : false;
                $conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Mini221190","datamace");

                $selecao = "SELECT id, RazaoSocial FROM Empresas";
                $empresas = mysqli_query($conecta,$selecao);

                $retorno = array();
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($empresas)) {
                  $retorno[] = $linha;
                }

                echo ($callback ? $callback . '(' : '') . json_encode($retorno) . ($callback? ')' : '');

                // fechar conecta
                mysqli_close($conecta);
                ?>
```

e criei um arquivo consulta.js e importei no formulario junto com a importação da callback.
Meu arquivo consulta.js:

```
  function retornarEmpresas(data){
              var empresas = "";
              $.each(data, function(chave,valor){
                empresas += '<option value="' + valor.id + '">' + valor.RazaoSocial + '</option>';
              });
              $('#empresas').html(empresas);
            }

            $('#empresas').change(function(e){
              var empresaID = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                data: "id=" + empresaID,
                url:"http://localhost:8080/retornar_produtos.php",
                async: false

              }).done(function(data){
                var produtos = "";
                $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor){
                  produtos += '<option value="' + valor.id + '">' + valor.Nome + '</option>';
                });
                $('#produtos').html(produtos);
              });
            });
```

Comment: Você criou as classes do Model Eloquent? Tem esse código para fornecer?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: No Laravel é só escrever `TransferenciaArquivo::with('produtoTransferenciaArquivos')->get()`  vai carregar, mas, o seu código está estranho, porque, é Laravel não é ?

Comment: Para consultar os produtos e as empresas, eu fiz em php puro, é que nao sei muito bem laravel. Tenho que colocar esse código q vc mandou na model ? e depois chama-lo aonde?

Comment: Fabio se tem que chamar no `Controller` !!!